# Create a file on remote server using ssh

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04

I want to create a file on a remote server using ssh but I am not able to do so. I have 3 remote server and I am writing a bash script to create files on each of them.

The command I am using is:

```
`ssh $1@$2 > /etc/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/config/test.sh <<EOL
broker.id=$3
listeners=$4
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.cleaner.enable=false
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
delete.topic.enable=true
ssl.client.auth=required
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL

EOL`
```

but it does not seem to work.

Comment: as an alternative, consider creating a file on your machine and copy it with `scp myfile username@remotehost:/the/place/to/copy` to the remote host

Comment: ya i thought of that option but was wondering why this is not working. And actually it is a properties file which is used to start the program so didn't wanted to keep changing it and then scp it

Comment: echo "stuff" | ssh user@host "cat - >> file"

Comment: Do you use your snippet somewhere in your script? 
Do you have a password-free access to your remote host (i.e. `id_rsa.pub` copied to the remote server). Otherwise you probably need to authorize on the remote host and that's probably why you

Comment: selyunin , yes i have id_rsa.pub. Actully all VM are in a cloud space so provisioning is done

Comment: @aet what aboout multiline stuff, it throws error

Comment: You could cat instead of echo, or anything really that feeds your text into stdin of the ssh process

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should work for you:

```
cat <<EOL | ssh $1@$2 'cat > /etc/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/config/test.sh'
broker.id=$3
listeners=$4
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
log.retention.hours=168
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
log.cleaner.enable=false
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
delete.topic.enable=true
ssl.client.auth=required
security.inter.broker.protocol=SSL

EOL
```

The first `cat` command takes its input from the [here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) (provided by the shell which expands the positional parameters, `$3` and `$4`) and its output is piped into the `ssh` command.

The `cat > /etc/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/config/test.sh` command is single-quoted as it should all be parsed as a single argument for the `ssh` command. If it’s not quoted, only the `cat` command by itself would be passed to the `ssh` command and the shell would parse the `>` as an instruction to redirect the output of the `ssh` command to a local file. This `cat` command runs on the remote server and gets its input from the `ssh` connection (if a filename isn’t specified as an operand for a `cat` command, it uses standard input instead).

---

The above command is actually a [useless use of cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) but I thought it might be easier for a shell-scripting newcomer to follow. You can actually shorten the first line by redirecting input for the `ssh` command directly from the here document:

```
ssh $1@$2 'cat > /etc/kafka/kafka_2.11-0.9.0.0/config/test.sh' <<EOL
```

This will work for Bash and other POSIX (standards-compliant) shells.